# Xcode 4.5.1 ios binary on ios 5.1.1 results in error

Tags: ios, xcode

I´ve just got a new Mac and I downloaded Xcode (4.5.1) from Appstore. By default when you create a new project (in my case using the Master/Detail template with Storyboard enabled) it targets ios 6.0 and the project runs fine on my iPhone that has been upgraded to 6.0.

To run it on my iPhone with 5.1.1 I change the Deployment target. Running on 5.1.1 when an item is added and displayed in the UITableView I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason:' -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1023b800'
```

This is the code that trows the error

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

From my previous iPhone projects I´m used to seeing this below the

```
if(cell == nil)
// Create the cell
```

But I assume I don´t need this as the Storyboard already has got a Cell added to the UITableView.

Any tips..?

Best regaards
Øystein

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can be found in the [[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:);

> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn´t see the difference between the new method with "forIndexPath" and the old without it..!

Comment: Yeah, I just hit this too. The reason I hit this was because I was creating a UITableViewController subclass. This code was auto-generated by Xcode, but commented out. Once I un-commented, it still compiled (bc I was using the iOS 6 library as the Base SDK). But running on the ios 5 simulator would crash hard.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the offending code line to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" ];
```

basically dropping `forIndexPath:indexPath` and it worked.  Now I am moving ahead with trying more code and will report back if this causes an issue.